# TypeError: Cannot read property 'calendar' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, fullcalendar

I'm building app by using react, typescript and [fullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/).

I want to in my root component setState from selected data range in fullcalendar component. When I select data range i get this error:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'calendar' of undefined - (page 1/2)
TypeError: Cannot read property 'getApi' of null - (page 2/2)

in this line

```
   useEffect(() => {
   -->   calendarApi = calendarComponentRef.current!.getApi();    
   });
```

This is my code:

```
import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/react';
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction';
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid';
import { WizardContext } from '../../ReservationWizard/ReservationWizard';
import { EventInput } from '@fullcalendar/core';

type CalendarProps = {
  startDate: Date;
  endDate: Date;
  setStartDate: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Date>>;
  setEndDate: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Date>>;
};

const Calendar: React.FC<CalendarProps> = (props) => {
  const { changePage, currentPage } = useContext(WizardContext);
  const calendarComponentRef = React.createRef<FullCalendar>();
  let calendarApi: any;

  useEffect(() => {
     calendarApi = calendarComponentRef.current!.getApi();
  });

  const customButtons = {
     previous: {
        text: '<',
        click() {
          calendarApi.prev();
        },
    },
    further: {
        text: '>',
        click() {
          calendarApi.next();
        },
   },
   };

   const getReservationTime = (event: EventInput) => {
      const { start, end } = event;
      if (start && end) {
         startDate = new Date(start.toString());
         endDate = new Date(end.toString());
         props.setStartDate(startDate);
         props.setEndDate(endDate);
     }
   };


  return (
    <div className='calendar-container'>
      <FullCalendar
        ref={calendarComponentRef}
        defaultView='dayGridMonth'
        plugins={[interactionPlugin, dayGridPlugin]}
        selectable={true}
        header={{
          left: '',
          center: 'previous, title, further',
          right: '',
        }}
        customButtons={customButtons}
        dateClick={getReservationTime}
        select={getReservationTime}
      />
     </div>
    );};

 export default Calendar;
```

If I remove from getReservationTime() this part of code:

```
 props.setStartDate(startDate);
 props.setEndDate(endDate);
```

All without set date range in setState is working correctly. I'm able to select in my calendar a lot of days without crashing app

Comment: `calendarComponentRef.current!.getApi()`, why did you put a `!` after `current`?

Comment: I'm using customButtons and I need access to functions of getApi. [This is official](https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar-example-projects/tree/master/react-typescript) FullCalendar project for react and ts. I moved this part of code from this repo.

Comment: @Pawel your comment doesn't answer @JMadelaine's question. You're being asked specifically why you included a `!` in your command. It looks like a typo. Have you tried removing it? According to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/react the command should be `calendarComponentRef.current.getApi()`.

Comment: It's not a typo, it's the TypeScript operator for "definitely exists". What I'm wondering is why it's being used to ignore the "possibly null" warnings from TypeScript, when in fact that value being null is the reason you're getting the error. The code you linked to also includes it, so it seems that you're just copying and pasting code without knowing why. You should really try to understand what's going on here rather than just copying code.

Comment: When using refs, you should always do a null check before trying to access properties of the ref. Check to see if `current` exists before calling `getApi`. Don't just silence TypeScriot warnings with `!`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment and help. I was changed logic of my code and now my app is working correctly. Unfortunately till today I don't have idea what was wrong in previous solution...